# Javascript not functioning after adding two variables

Tags: javascript

Ok, I have these input boxes.

```
<input 
   type="text" 
   name="amount" 
   class="validate[required] text-input" 
   id="amount">

<input type="text" 
       name="incfee" 
       id="incfee" 
       readonly>
```

And this is the javascript I have :-

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
     window.onload = function() {
        var amount = document.getElementById('amount');
        var incfee = document.getElementById('incfee');

        var fee = 0.01;

        amount.onkeyup = function() {
           var result = parseFloat(amount.value) * fee;
           // var result1 = result + amount;
           incfee.value = !isNaN(result) ? result : '';
        };
     }
  </script>
```

Now, the **problem** is, that if I **comment** the line `"var result1 = result + amount;"` and rename result1 to result in **incfee.value** , the value of the textbox (amount including fee) changes with the value in amount and everything works fine.
BUT, If I **uncomment** the line `var result1 = result + amount;` and change result to result 1 in **incfee.value**, the javascript doesn't works and no value is populated in the incfee textbox.
What mistake am I doing?
Thanks.

Comment: Check for errors in your browser's dev tools.

Comment: @J0e3gan This would most likely not result in an error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`var result1 = result + parseFloat(amount.value);`

Javacript doesnt know how to add a float and an input-object.

Comment: It actually does, but the result might be surprising.

Comment: Don't forget to convert that value, or you're gonna get a string concatenation.

Comment: I like learning about math with non-numbers.  I'm curious to know what a float + HTMLInputElement equals.

Comment: Might want to simplify those two lines to `var result1 = amount.value * (1 + fee);` and skip the intermediate step (and all the `parseFloat`s.

Comment: @Brandon - let's say the `result` equaled 0.01 . . . the "float + HTMLInputElement" computation would net the following string: "0.01[object HTMLInputElement]"

Comment: Makes sense... the concatenation of the .toString() calls.  I was hoping for something more dramatic.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.value` to get value of input text

```
var amount = document.getElementById('amount').value; 
var incfee = document.getElementById('incfee').value;
```

Comment: While you've got the right idea, simply modifying these two lines as you've shown would just further break his code.